# How do I fetch n-th row from Cassandra?

Tags: limit, cassandra, rows

I have column family with timestamp as row name and I want to fetch first 10 rows, second 10's, etc.

```
family = { //CF
    TimeUUID: value, 
    ...
```

I know that I can set column-limit for first query and get first n-th rows, but how can I get next n-th rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_range_slices](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API) (use the last key from the previous query as the first key in the next query)

Comment: yeah, but if I need 10 rows starting from 1000, I'm need to iterate through all data-set?

Comment: numeric offset instead of column-name cannot be done efficiently. (this is true of relational dbs as well, so either way you should get out of the habit of using it.  see http://www.percona.com/ppc2009/PPC2009_mysql_pagination.pdf)